# View appears on screen only in iPad and IPhone 6.1 simulator

Tags: xcode

I have around 20 apps with a picture on the screen and a microphone and speaker at the top of the screen so people can record their voice and play it back. All of these work fine on devices and the simulators.

I'm finishing up a new app that uses text instead of pictures and I put either a UIWebView with scrolling enabled or a UIScrollView on the screen. Both screens display with the UIButtons for the microphone and speaker on the screen when I run it in the simulator in 6.1. Neither recording button appears in other versions of the simulator or on devices running iOS 5.1.1 or iOS 6.1.2.

I just updated all of the apps last week and they run fine on the simulator and on devices and I've had no feedback from users that the recording buttons are missing. The only difference I can think of for this app is that it uses a ScrollView. If I look at what views are supposed to be on the screen, ( NSLog(@"%@", self.view.subviews); ) the microphone and speaker have been placed there, they just aren't visible. They're the opaque buttons on top of the hidden buttons. The ones at 10000 aren't used in this app.

```
   "<UIWebView: 0x28dd40; frame = (30 100; 964 624); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x28ddd0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x25fac0; frame = (0 137; 90 90); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x25fb50>>",
"<UIButton: 0x283210; frame = (0 137; 90 90); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2832a0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x284390; frame = (13.5 317; 90 90); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x284420>>",
"<UIButton: 0x2855d0; frame = (13.5 317; 90 90); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x285660>>",
"<UIButton: 0x286660; frame = (13.5 317; 90 90); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2866f0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x287940; frame = (10000 3; 90 90); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2879d0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x288b60; frame = (10000 3; 90 90); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x288bf0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x289cd0; frame = (10000 3; 90 90); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x289d60>>",
"<UIButton: 0x28b010; frame = (10000 3; 90 90); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x28b0a0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x28c2f0; frame = (411 5; 202 16); text = ' '; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x28c390>>"
```

When I put the WebView and ScrollView on the screen I use

```
[self.parentView insertSubview:self.webView atIndex:0]; and 
[self.parentView insertSubview:self.quizView atIndex:0];
```

So they should be on the first layer in background. Even so, their bounds don't touch the recording buttons. Does scrolling do something that I'm not aware of or is there somewhere else I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the images used in the buttons weren't included in the target.

For some reason, this did not cause a problem in the simulator running 6.1 but did in other simulators. For reasons unknown, an error wasn't generated when the image couldn't be found when running on the device or other simulator versions.